# How do I use `ndarray_stats::CorrelationExt` on a `polars::prelude::DataFrame`?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm trying to calculate the covariance of a data frame in Rust. The `ndarray_stats` crate defines [such a function](https://docs.rs/ndarray-stats/0.5.0/ndarray_stats/trait.CorrelationExt.html#tymethod.cov) for arrays, and I can produce an array from a `DataFrame` using [`to_ndarray`](https://docs.rs/polars/0.14.7/polars/prelude/struct.DataFrame.html#method.to_ndarray). The compiler is happy if I use the example in the documentation (`a`), but if I try to use it on an `Array2` produced from a `DataFrame`, this doesn't work:

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use ndarray_stats::CorrelationExt;

fn cov(df: &DataFrame) -> Vec<f64> {
    // Both of these are Array2<f64>s
    let mat = df.to_ndarray::<Float64Type>().unwrap();
    let a = arr2(&[[1., 3., 5.], [2., 4., 6.]]);

    let x = a.cov(1.).unwrap();
    let y = mat.cov(1.).unwrap();
}
```

```
   |
22 |     let y = mat.cov(1.).unwrap();
   |                 ^^^ method not found in `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
```

Why does the compiler allow the definition of `x` but not `y`? How can I fix the code such that `y` can be assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a dependency version mismatch.`polars-core` [depends on `ndarray` version 0.13.x as of 0.14.7](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/py-polars-v0.8.12/polars/polars-core/Cargo.toml#L119), whereas
[`ndarray-stats` 0.5 requires `ndarray` 0.15](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray-stats/0.5.0/dependencies). As you use the latest version of `ndarray` in your project as well, the 2D array type of `x` will be compatible with the extension trait `CovExt` provided by `ndarray-stats`, but `y` will not.

Regardless of the nature of a type in a library, once multiple semver-incompatible versions of a library are included, their types will typically not be interchangeable. In other words, even though these `Array2<_>` may appear to be the same type, they are treated as different types by the compiler.

The multiple versions of a crate in a package can be found by inspecting the output of `cargo tree -d`, which shows only duplicate dependencies and the reverse tree that shows the crates depending on them. Duplicates do not necessarily pose a problem, but problems arise if the project consumes more than one API directly.

The lowest common denominator at the time of writing is to downgrade `ndarray` to 0.13 and `ndarray-stats` to 0.3, which [also has the method `cov`](https://docs.rs/ndarray-stats/0.3.0/ndarray_stats/trait.CorrelationExt.html#tymethod.cov). It may also be worth looking into contributing to the polars project in order to update `ndarray` there.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. Is there any way to know how to when a dependency clash is is happening, and avoid it?

Comment: Would it be an option for the dependent (polars) to re-export their version of ndarray, so that consumers can always rely on that version instead of declaring their own import?

Comment: I don't think that would help, because at no point am I needing to import `ndarray` here. I'm obtaining an `ndarray` from `DataFrame.to_ndarray()` and "passing it into" `CorrelationExt.cov`. If there is a version mismatch that can't ever work.